# Dynamically add and remove form rows with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple form (built using the Semantic ui react library) that consists of a row with a few inputs, my intention is to have the form default to just this single row on initial render but allow the user to click a button to add an extra row, which works fine. Where I need help is giving the ability to delete a row before the user finally submits it all.

I have my form field stored in an initial variable outside the component (for ease of visual for me more than anything):

```
const formField = (
    <div style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "row" }}>
        <Form.Select
            label="Exercise"
            placeholder="Select an exercise"
            options={exercises}
        />
        <Form.Input label="Sets" placeholder="Enter your sets" type="number" />
        <Form.Input label="Reps" placeholder="Enter your reps" type="number" />
    </div>
);
```

And then I store this in initial state:

```
const [formRow, setFormRow] = useState([formField]);
```

The jsx consists of a button that concats a new form field (row) to the state, and then I render all the fields to the page, giving me extra rows

```
<Form>
            {formRow.map((item, i) => (
                <Form.Group inline widths="equal" key={i}>
                    {item}
                    <Icon
                        name="close"
                        onClick={() => setFormRow((cur) => cur.splice(i, 1))}
                    />
                </Form.Group>
            ))}
            <Button
                color="orange"
                content="Add an exercise"
                onClick={() => setFormRow((prev) => prev.concat([formField]))}
            />
        </Form>
```

I add a delete icon for each row when I map over and render to the page, but I can't get this feature to work. I tried to just use splice to remove the relevant row but that doesn't work... it'll also deletes any rows after the row I click on (not quite sure why)

[The form basically looks as such](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLR52.jpg)

Does anyone know how I can add a feature to delete each row on dynamically created form jsx?

Thank.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will work to delete a row from your form

```js
<Icon
    name="close"
    onClick={() => setFormRow((cur) => [...cur.slice(0, i), ...cur.slice(i+1)])}
/>
```

Also, I would suggest storing only the data for each row in your state in stead of storing jsx.
Edit:
Example of deleting one element from the list

```js
const index = 2
const list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
console.log(list)
const newList = [...list.slice(0, index), ...list.slice(index + 1)]
console.log(newList)
```

```
enter code here
```

Comment: It still has the same issue I already encounter unfortunately. It proceeds to delete all the rows that come after the single one that I want to delete as well.

Comment: It will not. if you look at the code I'm only deleting the one at index `i`. I have attached an example to the answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for error happens in your code in this line:

```
onClick={() => setFormRow((cur) => cur.splice(i, 1))}
```

the returned value of `SPLICE` method is not the ammended array, it returns the array of removed values.

From MOZILLA docs:

> **Return value**

> An array containing the deleted elements.
>
> If only one element is removed, an array of one element is returned.
>
> If no elements are removed, an empty array is returned.

And, you should not use `SPLICE` when you want to update React state, this method mutates the original array. Use `FILTER` instead.

I see on your code, you write separated JSX for `formField` but I think it is unneccessary, because, you only write it one time.

I suggest another approach for your problem, it is simplified example (without semantic), you can see it in this runnable online example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-wescoff-lnj71?file=/src/App.js:265-316

Or in this code below (the same with the above URL):

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [formRows, setFormRows] = useState([{ id: 1 }]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("formRows: ", formRows);
  });

  return (
    <div>
      {formRows.map((row) => (
        <div>
          <input></input>
          <input></input>
          <button
            onClick={() =>
              setFormRows(formRows.filter((fr) => fr.id !== row.id))
            }
          >
            remove
          </button>
        </div>
      ))}
      <button
        onClick={() => setFormRows([...formRows, { id: formRows.length + 1 }])}
      >
        add
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```